# Check individual mysql table rows and apply a function only to them

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table with different users (differ by id) https://i.stack.imgur.com/uHUrh.jpg

Every time I trigger a php file to run to process the next turn, I have this part of the code responsible for updating that specific table:

```
$get_turn_update = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM turn_update") or die (mysqli_error($connect));
while ($user_turn_update = mysqli_fetch_assoc($get_turn_update)) {
    if ($user_turn_update['residenceTurns'] > 0) {
        $residencesBuilt = ceil($user_turn_update['residence'] / $user_turn_update['residenceTurns']);
        $residences_turn_update = mysqli_query($connect, "UPDATE turn_update SET residenceTurns = residenceTurns - 1") or die (mysqli_error($connect));
        $residences_update = mysqli_query($connect, "UPDATE turn_update SET residence = residence - '".$residencesBuilt."'") or die (mysqli_error($connect));
        $residences_built_update = mysqli_query($connect, "UPDATE buildings SET residence = residence + '".$residencesBuilt."'") or die (mysqli_error($connect));
    }
}
```

Basically, the 'residence' column is the amount of residences that will be built over the course of the remaining turns - the 'residenceTurns' column.

The problem is that when the user with id 3, for example, gets his residences "built", and the residenceTurns decremented by 1, the other users (in this case id 4), even if they do not have any residences in construction get the same amount of turns removed (-1) and amount of residences (depending on the amount there is).

So for instance, if we start with such parameters:

- id | residence | residenceTurns
- 3 | 10 | 2
- 4 | 0 | 0

in 1 turn we will have

- id | residence | residenceTurns
- 3 | 5 | 1
- 4 | -5 | -1

in 2 turns we will have

- id | residence | residenceTurns
- 3 | 0 | 0
- 4 | -10 | -2

What I need is if a row (a user) has an amount of residences building, it affects only him and is processed individually for every user.

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not using a WHERE clause in your update statements, therefore, you are updating your entire table every time. Limit your query to the specific residence by providing a WHERE clause, such as:

```
UPDATE residence SET turns = turns - 1 WHERE id = residence['id']
```

I'm on my phone, this is pseudo code, but that should help you out.

Comment: ...also, adding `WHERE residenceTurns > 0` in the first `SELECT` would mean that the `if`-statement in the loop isn't necessary.

Comment: Magnus, thanks for that insight. That might work if I have only residences to take care of, but its actually followed by another 20 if statements within that while loop. They are all identical, just different buildings and their respective turns. Would you have a suggestion for that case? I saved an example of the code in this jsfiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/5yvcurmv/

Comment: you're looping over a bunch of 'keys' from the user_turn_updates array, you could store just the keys in another array, and loop over them, instead of explicitly calling each one in an 'if' statement.

Comment: Cody, I'm not sure what you mean under 'keys', would you be so kind to show an example from which I could learn to apply it like in your original answer?

Comment: Sure, a key is like so, $array['thisisthekey']. So, if you create an array with all of the keys that you want to loop over, such as ['residenceTurns', 'fighterPadTurns'], then you can loop over each key with a while statement, without having to write each if statement, you can just write the one in a while statement.